# What is wrong with my betta fish? Fin rot? Velvet?

Tags: aquarium, fish, freshwater, betta

In the picture submitted you can clearly see a healthy betta fish in the top 3 pictures. Those pictures are from May 2017 when he was first brought home from the pet store. The bottom 3 pictures are from last night.

This is a betta fish. I wasn't aware of the type of care that these fish truly need. I did however do weekly 100% water changes adding conditioner to the water each time. I fed him 2x every day. He was active sometimes but preferred to stay in some artificial plants found in the tank. Last night I changed the water and that's when I noticed something was truly wrong. After I put him in the tank it stayed at the surface and I could see a clear struggle to breathe. Or as you can see in the pictures, it sunk to the bottom and stayed there for a while. I tried feeding it but it would not move. It did not even acknowledge the food.
I am ashamed to admit that I have yet to get a kit to test these values so I am unaware.

Currently it is in a 1.5 gallon tank. This tank has been set up since May 14 2017. I do not have a filter. Again, I've been misinformed about the care that these fish need. I read online that if you do weekly 100% water changes you do not need a filter.

There is only 1 fish in the tank. I've had this fish for about 4 months

I have added a new betta hammock last night. Also, I added a heater about a week ago. I also noticed that [this new conditioner](https://www.chewy.com/aqueon-betta-bowl-plus-water/dp/130982?utm_source=google-product&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=f&utm_content=Aqueon&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8suZoZmT1gIVm7XACh2R3wpYEAQYAyABEgIhM_D_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) that I bought has white flakes in it? I have purchased this conditioner before and it did not have white flakes in it.

I know I have failed as a fish owner and I did not realize the damage that I have caused it. I know it is not much but I recently order [a new tank](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002DRLESA) and am waiting for it to arrive.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any images in your post. Are you sure you included them? [Here's the formatting guide](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: A 9 l aquarium is still very small. You can get a 20 l or 30 l glass tank for 20 € from a local store right now and get you fish into an appropriate environment immediately (after cycling). In such a tank you can add live plants and other things for more appealing environment. Whilst theoretically such mini plastic worlds work, they don't in real life (see many [other questions regarding suffering betta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17533/help-increase-betta-fish-lifespan-beyond-1-5-weeks?rq=1) on this platform). You should at least try to immitate nature in an aquarium.

Comment: The linked question contains reasonable, _minimal_ criteria for a betta aquarium.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an answer for you other than it is most likely NOT fin rot. A fish will not develop fin rot in such a short and sudden period of time. I feel you need some encouragement. You have not failed as a fish owner. The people who failed are the people who push 'perfect for betta' products that meet almost 0 of the things betta need to live long healthy lives. You have actually succeeded as a fish owner because you have obviously researched and are working towards improving your facilities to improve the health of your betta. Don't blame yourself blame the money hungry market. I also have some tips for you. 100% water changes will stress your fish I suggest doing a 40% water change every 5 days to reduce stress on the fish. I would stop useless the conditioner with the white flakes as I'm not sure what they are. To keep waste in the aquarium down I'd only feed your fish once a day with 1 day without food. I personally feed my betta 4 pellets of food with a fast on Wednesdays.

Answer (score 2):

It's swim bladder disease.

[Here's an article](https://www.cuteness.com/article/treat-fish-swim-bladder-disease) about it:

> A betta with this disease will either float involuntarily along the surface or they will sink to the bottom of the bowl. Additional symptoms are a lopsided body position while swimming, lethargic behavior and swelling of the stomach. Usually caused by over-feeding and constipation, swim bladder disease is not contagious and is easy to treat.

The article goes on to explain some treatment options, like using a pea. There are other medicinal alternatives too, like MelaFix.

> I read online that if you do weekly 100% water changes you do not need a filter.

Correct. A filter never hurts, though.

> I also noticed that this new conditioner that I bought has white flakes in it? I have purchased this conditioner before and it did not have white flakes in it.

This particular brand of water conditioner is prone for this, especially if the bottle you bought is near or past expiration. Basically, the conditioner dries on the bottle - on the rim, in the grooves, in the cap, etc - and then when you pour it, the flakes get in. They are harmless. They eventually dissipate into the water.

> I recently order a new tank and am waiting for it to arrive.

Ok, that won't help your fish get better though. He needs special treatment, like the webpage says.